# JavaScript keypress event get end value of textarea

Tags: javascript, mootools, dom-events, keypress, keyboard-events

I was wondering if it were possible to get the end result in the `keypress` event?
Currently, I am using the `keyup` because it is activated *after* the user has done text editing in a texteara, but I have written a method that does something similar using the Mootools library:

```
input.addEvent("keypress", function (input) {
    var previous_result = this.value;
    var end_result = this.value + input.key;
});
```

However, this method is horrible when dealing with special keys such as backspace, or if the user chooses to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> && <kbd>Backspace</kbd> in which case the value of the input element would not be "an empty string".

I'm curious because I have observed Google's search engine sending XMLHttpRequest AND mutating the page **before** the `keyup` event triggered.
Additionally, the input they use manages to overcome my problem of removing entire text while still enjoying the luxury of `keypress`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills : Tried it, the value lags behind actual result in `keydown` :<

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will make it work:

```
input.addEvent( "keypress", function ( input ) {    
    setTimeout(function () {
        input.value // returns the updated value
    }, 0 );    
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/yQQ5P/ (I use built-in API, as I don't know Mootools)

So, you use a zero-timeout which acts as a yield. This gives the browser's UI thread an opportunity to updated the input's value.

Comment: Whoah, just enveloped the code with this and it works like a charm, hvala puno!