# Why does this jQuery input value checker not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, input

I need to check all the inputs to see if they are filled, in which case the submit button would become pressable and the user can submit their data safely:

```
unfilled = false;
$('.add-field').keypress(function(){
    $('.add-field').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() === ''){
            unfilled = true;
        } else {
            unfilled = false;
        }
    })
    console.log(unfilled);
});
```

This code works, but it has a strange twist; as the last empty input gains a character, it still returns `true`. If an input gains another character, only then it will return `false`. I am confused by this, as I understand that the `.each()` function is fired after a character has been added and the value of the input has been updated. Consequently, I do not see why it does not register that value.

Comment: How come you feel the need to check every `add-field` when changing just one of them? Why not just check itself? The others would also just check themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use filter and use keyup event instead for del keys:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mGXY5/)

```
$('.add-field').keyup(function () {
    var unfilled = !! $('.add-field').filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value) === ""
    }).length;
    console.log(unfilled);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should set `unfilled` to `false` before entering the loop (but INSIDE the `keyup`).

In the loop you should only set `unfilled` to `true` when a field is emty and not set it to `false` again, otherwise you'll only know if the last field is filled in.

Comment: the code in the question still sets `unfilled` to `false` inside the loop

Comment: oh, wait, you removed the loop.. now i don't follow anymore :P

Comment: I am sorry, I am updating it as I go. I thought I didn't need the loop. Upon further investigation I do. Here is a JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UzP4s/

Comment: Unfortunately setting `unfilled` to `false` before entering the loop does not work.

Comment: You should set `unfilled` to false before the loop, but inside the `keyup`! Otherwise `unfilled` will always be true after the first time the loop ran and there was a missing value.

Answer (score 0):

Here `===` means it is matching exactly the data types:

```
if($(this).val() === ''){
```

Replace it with `==` :

```
 if($(this).val() == ''){
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is an 'issue' when using the **KeyPress**-event, because the Browser's UI Thread did not update the input field's value yet. Therefore the value currently is still 'empty' and thus `true` is returned; you can either use the **KeyUp**-event or try something like this: [JavaScript keypress event get end value of textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841739/javascript-keypress-event-get-end-value-of-textarea)